# multiple query use resultset of previous query in one php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use a value that I receive from a MySQL query and then do an insert but it's not working.  I'm getting an syntax error but the Insert Query is correct.

The select query returns an amount which I'm checking and then the program should do the insert query.

```
    <?php
require 'header.php';

$resID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['resID']);
$materialen_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['materialen_id']);
$aantal = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['aantal']);
$effectief_gebruikt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['effectief_gebruikt']);
$opmerking = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['opmerking']);
//$datum_van = date('d-m-Y', $_POST['datum_van']);
//$datum_tot = date('d-m-Y', $_POST['datum_tot']);
$datum_van = $_POST['datum_van'];
$datum_tot = $_POST['datum_tot'];


$sql = "SELECT `aantal_beschikbaar` 
        FROM `materialen` 
        WHERE `id` = $materialen_id";
        
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $tot = $row['aantal_beschikbaar'];
    echo 'totaal: ' . $tot;
}



$sql2 = "SELECT `aantal` FROM `materialen_per_reservatie`
        WHERE `materialen_id` = $materialen_id";  
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    //$aant = $row['aantal'];
    //echo $aant
    echo $row['aantal'];
}

$besch = ($tot - $aant);
echo 'beschikbaar: ' . $besch;



/*$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `materialen_per_reservatie`
        WHERE `reservaties_id` = $resID
        AND   `materialen_id` = $materialen_id";
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());*/

if($besch > $aantal){



        $string2 = "INSERT INTO `materialen_per_reservatie`(`reservaties_id`, `materialen_id`, `aantal`, `effectief_gebruikt`, `opmerking`, `datum_van`, `datum_tot`) VALUES ($resID, $materialen_id, $aantal, $effectief_gebruikt, '$opmerking', '$datum_van', '$datum_tot')";
        mysql_query($string2) or die(mysql_error());  

        
}      
  
require 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Can you echo $string2 before it's executed, and then copy and paste it into mysql without error?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: echo 'string: ' . $string2;

not printing anything

Comment: @JimmyGeers Have you tested the `if` statement `if($besch > $aantal){`? When I run your code in codepad, it echos `$string2`. http://codepad.org/x1mim4Ot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the error is on only the insert query...

Your insert query is missing a needed space:

```
INSERT INTO `materialen_per_reservatie` (`reservaties_id`, `materialen_id`, `aantal`, `effectief_gebruikt`, `opmerking`, `datum_van`, `datum_tot`) VALUES ($resID, $materialen_id, $aantal, $effectief_gebruikt, '$opmerking', '$datum_van', '$datum_tot')
```

Add a space after `materialen_per_reservatie`. And I'm not sure you need all of the quotes.

```
INSERT INTO materialen_per_reservatie (reservaties_id, materialen_id, aantal, effectief_gebruikt, opmerking, datum_van, datum_tot) VALUES ($resID, $materialen_id, $aantal, $effectief_gebruikt, '$opmerking', '$datum_van', '$datum_tot')
```

Comment: The Query is working well if i run it into mysql. I realy thing there is a fault when im trying to do 2 query's afther eachother.

Comment: @JimmyGeers Have you set your MySQL to run multiple queries?

Comment: @JimmyGeers Try adding `allowMultiQueries=true` to your connection string.

Comment: It's for an android application. the data get's send from java with HTTP post. i don't think i can set that what your saying.

Comment: @JimmyGeers Don't worry about it. I don't think multiple queries is the issue.